# Set up a footer that stays in the footer area when resize WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, footer

I am struggling to set up a footer in a WPF application. I want my footer to be a simple text and nothing more and I want it to stay still when resizing the page. The page contains a menu on in the top, a button, that is put into a canvas because I don't want it to change its size. I also have a textBox that is in a grid and I want it to be resized with the page. Under the textBox I want to setup the footer (I set it up with a label). Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this ? I tried everything ..

Here is the main part of my .XAML file:

```
<Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="{Binding x}"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_View">
                <MenuItem Header="Logs" Comm`enter code here`and="{Binding y}" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Canvas Margin="0,0,-0.4,432.6">
            <Button Command="{Binding z}" Name="Button" Canvas.Top="22" Width="122" Height="24" Canvas.Left="10">Download Images</Button>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Margin="0,0,-0.4,432.6">
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="108" Canvas.Left="10" Height="25" Canvas.Top="47">Status</Label>
        </Canvas>
        <TextBox Name="MessageDisplay" Text="{Binding q, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}"  Margin="10,73,10.6,44.6"/>
        <Label Margin="0,475,-0.4,-0.4">Footer !!!</Label>
</Grid>
```

This is how it looks when I run the app:
[Before any resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShgdM.png)

and this is what happens after I maximize the page :
[maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Dfc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be making use of `RowDefinitions` for your `Grid` to do this reliably. Don't set canvas postions and margins to specific areas or your resizing will never look right. Margin is a great tool, but it should be set in the scope of the area the control is in within the layout

Specify your row definitions and their height. Here's an example using your code. Rows start at index 0. Take this example and look up some more information about specifying grid row and column layouts in WPF. This should get you started on the right path though.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Command="{Binding x}"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_View">
            <MenuItem Header="Logs"  />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Command="{Binding z}" Name="Button" Margin="5" Width="122" Height="24" >Download Images</Button>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="2">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="108"  Height="25" >Status</Label>
    </Canvas>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Name="MessageDisplay" Text="{Binding q, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}"  Margin="5"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="4" >Footer !!!</Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tronald . This works perfectly . I will be researching more what you've said.